# spark overwrite functionality delete before uploading files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there any way that spark overwrite doesn't delete the files at target location before overwriting them.
I am using below code to overwrite files, but this operation takes around 5-6 mins.
During this time this path remains empty till new files get overwrite. End users complain about this unavailability.

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("<s3 location>")
```

Is there any other way that i can use?

Comment: you can do this way.. write data to different directory & point your table to that location and then remove old directory & in case if you job fails anywhere your data is still available in old directory.

Comment: Question remains same only if we change the directory it will then do the same only. Could you please elaborate